# How to stop computation based on prior input values, if the input was changed?

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to specify in shiny that only the most recent input value is used for execution and all computation that may still be running based on prior input values is stopped?

Please see the following example app for demonstration. If I quickly change the input from "a" to "b" to "c" to "d" to "e", the calculation will take 20 seconds, but I would like it to only take 5 seconds after I selected "e".

```
library(shiny)

# ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("letters", "", choices = letters[1:5]),
  verbatimTextOutput("letters")
)

# server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$letters <- renderPrint({
    Sys.sleep(5)
    input$letters
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `debounce` function. It will slow down a reactive expression in a certain time window.

You should see the effects in the example below.

From the debounce info:

> Debouncing means that every invalidation from r will be held for the
> specified time window. If r invalidates again within that time window,
> then the timer starts over again. **This means that as long as
> invalidations continually arrive from r within the time window, the
> debounced reactive will not invalidate at all**. Only after the
> invalidations stop (or slow down sufficiently) will the downstream
> invalidation be sent.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("letters", "", choices = letters[1:5]),
  verbatimTextOutput("letters")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  letter <- reactive({
    Sys.sleep(2)
    input$letters
  }) %>% debounce(500)
  output$letters <- renderText({
    print("Printing the letter")
    letter()
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```